# Play sound(music) while cordova app is background on WP8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I tried Cordova Media Plugin and HTML5 Audio on Windows Phone 8.1 but when I press back and send app to background media stops playing.

How I can get over this problem? Is there any other plugin for play audio for WP8?